# Troubles implementing - Navigation Templates for Android Auto

Tags: android-auto

Hi im trying to implement a simple list of places with dummy coordinates with "PlaceListMapTemplate" and i need make two things after that

1.- Show a route preview with "RoutePreviewNavigationTemplate" from my current location to dummy coordinates

2.- Start Navigation

But I dont found how to do that in official documentation. Someone could help me?